# How do i enable click tracking in UI

Tags: civimail

I am using SparkPost for mail delivery of CiviCRM mass mailing.  SparkPost analytics show targeted and bounced emails etc but shows zero for clicks and opens.  How can i enable tracking of clicks and opens?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your sparkpost account(https://app.sparkpost.com) and click on 'Account' and then 'SMTP RELAY' and click on radio button 'Enable Tracking'. This will make sure tracking of clicks and opens.